# Elasticsearch serivce not found

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I'm trying to integrate elasticsearch into my symfony application. But I couldn't find any appropriate example on the internet. Now I'm getting this service not found error:

> Service "fos_elastica.finder.inscriptions.inscription" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\SearchController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session", "templating" and "twig" services. Unless you need extra laziness, try using dependency injection instead. Otherwise, you need to declare it using "SearchController::getSubscribedServices()".

For:

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.inscriptions.inscription');
```

As:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\
>   ServiceNotFoundException

I don't know how to solve this problem because of insufficient experience with Symfony. Does anyone know how to solve this or any Elasticsearch example with Symfony on the internet?
Thanks!

Comment: You have a lot of examples [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/elasticsearch) for symfony application. Just do ctrl+f `symfony`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your config/services.yaml file you have to bind this service as argument for your controller like that:

```
App\Controller\SearchController:
    bind:
        $finder: '@fos_elastica.finder.inscriptions.inscription'
```

Then you can use it in your controller by injecting it through autowiring:

```
public function index($finder) {
    // your code here
}
```

For more information refer to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#fetching-services).

Comment: Thank you! I could connect it as service and request, so your code solved my problem!